# Where to get php_memcached.dll file for wamp server

Tags: php, windows, memcached, wamp, php-5.4

halo i am really confused in the installation of memcached on my windows system. and then on my php side i couldn't find any php_memcached.dll file for php5.4.16 version. after a long searching i found a file for [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/) php_memcache.dll [not memcached]. so in my pc memcached were installed and i am using memcache with php ext. my question is how to enable memcached on php extension so that the memcached class would be available to use..

please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Win32 binary version of memcached available here http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip

Installation : http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine

Comment: but here the author says php_memcache.dll [not memcached] right..?

Comment: @tradebel123 In your php.ini, have you checked php_memcached.dll exists? (not php_memcache.dl)

Answer (score -2):

You can try OpenServer: mongodb, memcache, mysql, postgre